# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not be empty

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite, illegalargumentexception

What is the problem? It was working as well while I updated Ubuntu's software

**Main.class**

```
package okt.springbootstarter.test;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);

    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I don't know where is the problem?

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Include it in the post

Comment: lol he means have your code as text...

Comment: edited.  @rollstuhlfahrer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fix it.

```
>echo $HOSTNAME
```

> xyz

```
>sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

and

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

changed

```
127.0.0.1 xyz
```

it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.

Try this out, it looks like you are running a wrong class file.
Go to Java file which contains `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

e.g (default content):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this import :

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
```

to this :

```
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
```

And after clean and re build maven